# Access Attributes of object inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I am working on a winforms application using C#. I have a dictionary with specific objects, the object have attributes Id and DocType. How can i access the attributes of every object in a foreach statement. i Am trying with the following code but is not working. Any help pls?

```
foreach (var doc in crs.DocDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( doc.Id);
                 Console.WriteLine(doc.docType);

            }
```

Comment: The implicit type local variable makes you confused about the type of the dictionary's elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `foreach` on a dictionary you get a sequence of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`; try:

```
foreach (var doc in crs.DocDictionary.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(doc.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.docType);
}
```

or:

```
foreach (var pair in crs.DocDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value.docType);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Just make sure that you have a type Dictionay<TKey, TValue>, so you don't need to box it to anyhing else, like ((Document)pair.Value).Id.

Comment: when i am typing pair.Value. , i cant see the attributes Id and docType. I can see only .compareTo , ToString , GetType, GetHashCode, GetTypeCode and Equals.

Comment: @Andre that isn't a box/unbox

Comment: @user1292656 what is the **exact** type of the dictionary?